# Integral Power Rule Step-by-step

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Real quick, two things: I'm sorry if my notation or terminology is incorrect, and I know what I'm asking isn't strictly necessary for my studies, but writing something out step by step helps me to understand math intuitively.

I have spent a while thinking about this and cannot figure out where to go next.

I am taking Calc I and I understand differentiation intuitively and can derive functions using the various rules provided, while also understanding why they work and being able to do the steps manually.

So, for the power rule, I can show you the why of:

$$f(x) = x^n$$
$$f'(x) = nx^{n-1}$$

I also understand that to take the antiderivative, you reverse the process. I also know why the antiderivative provides a sum. Since I can't write it out step by step, though, I am not satisfied.

How can I show, algebraically, that
$$F(x^n) = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

So far (and I don't know how right I am, but I think I am close), I've gotten this far on my own:
$$f(x) = x^n$$
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=0}^n \left[\frac{x}{n} \cdot f\left(i\cdot\frac{x}{n}\right)\right] = F(x)$$

How do I evaluate this limit? How do I cross this threshold to reach the final form of the antiderivative? I have looked through google and this site on my own for a solution, but I can't seem to come across how to proceed.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: "I also know why the antiderivative provides a sum". False!

Comment: Did I commit some kind of SE faux pas? Can you explain why?

Comment: @Kegan don't worry, you've asked a great first question. You used LaTeX and have provided evidence that you've really thought about this! MathFacts comment (whether or not it is right) is not very helpful.

Comment: @graydad That makes me feel better. Thank you for showing me how to use cdot and brackets!

Comment: @Kegan not a problem, glad to have you on SE :) I believe I know the problem you have run into and am typing an answer up.

Comment: @Kegan Hey I know you may not be interested in this question any more, but just in case, here is what you need to calculate the integral rule step-by-step. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

This page discusses the general closed form of $$\sum_{i=1}^ki^k$$

Comment: @graydad I am! I was positively delighted to be able to rather quickly reduce my expression after your helpful answer. Nearly a week later and you've provided me with even further musings. My thanks are in direct proportion to how elated I feel; not exaggerated! It's more than I had hoped for when I asked for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what the problem boils down to: You need to have a closed formula for summing $$\sum_{i=1}^ni^k$$ I know of such a formula for $k=1,2,3$ and a buddy of mind derived one for $k=4$, but beyond that I don't know that there is a general formula for any $k$. For $k=1$ we know $$\sum_{i=1}^ni^1 = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ So if you had been interested in finding the antiderivative of $f(x)=x$, you evaluate the sum as you correctly outlined: $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left[\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{x}{n} \cdot f\left(i\cdot\frac{x}{n}\right)\right] = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left[\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{x}{n} \cdot \frac{xi}{n}\right] \\ = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left[\frac{x^2}{n^2}\sum_{i=0}^n i\right]$$ It is valid to move the $\frac{x^2}{n^2}$ outside the sum since we are summing over $i$. Now use the closed formula above to get  $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left[\frac{x^2}{n^2}\sum_{i=0}^n i\right] = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left[\frac{x^2}{n^2}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right] \\ = \frac{x^2}{2}\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left[\frac{n(n+1)}{n^2} \right] \\ = \frac{x^2}{2}$$ which is clearly the desired result. Again, you can find closed form sums for $k=2,3$ and maybe $4$ somewhere out there, but unless you know a general formula for an arbitrary positive integer $k$, your integral power rule options are limited.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I cannot express enough my gratitude for all of the help! I'm going to write this down and toy around with it until I'm comfortable.

Comment: @Kegan happy to help! I remember running into this wall when I was in calc 1. I encourage you to press onward and find the antiderivative of $x^2$ using the fact that $$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$ Good luck :)

Comment: @graydad is possible to use induction for $x^n$?

Comment: @ReinhildVanRosenú presumably it's possible? I can't say for sure. Here is the result you'd want to prove inductively. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula You might look over the proof available on the wiki page and see if you can make it into an inductive argument.